# How to migrate a Private Chain to POS

Tags: private-blockchain, eth-2.0, migration

I run a POW private chain and would like to update it to POS.
Does anyone have already performed such migration? Should I mimick the different phases (0,1,1.5 and 2) or it is possible to apply the full stack of change at once?
what does it imply in terms of down-time of the network?

Comment: The Ethereum mainnet migration hasn't been completed until then you'll have to wait.